# Python - Sympy - Solving equations numerically for multiple parameters in a grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, equation-solving, lambdify

A given equation depends on an unknown variable (`y`) and a set of parameters. I would like to numerically solve for `y`, given each element of a grid with values of the parameters.

A simplified example of my attempted solution is as follows (`y` is the unknown variable and `x` is the parameter):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
x,y=sp.symbols('x y')
xgrid=np.arange(1,6)
f = sp.lambdify(x,sp.nsolve(x**2+y,y,2),"numpy")
print(f(xgrid))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> expected a one-dimensional and numerical function.

I was expecting to receive a vector with `y=-x**2` for every value `x` in `xgrid`.

Please notice that the actual function of interest is not `y=-x**2` as in the example, but a non-linear function that is implicit in both `x` in `y`.

Am I forced to do a loop over each value in the `grid`, or can I still use `lambdify` somehow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `sympy.lambdify` is to transform *symbolic* expressions into numerical ones. It makes no sense "lambdyfing" `sympy.nsolve` as the latter is (by default) a numerical function. If you need to define a "wrapper" function for `sympy.nsolve` you should do so by using the standard python approach.

```
def f(x):
    y = sp.symbols('y')
    return float(sp.nsolve(x**2+y,y,2))
```

Now calling `f(xgrid)`, where `xfrid` is an `ndarray` makes no sense as the function accepts scalar arguments. You need to write a loop. If you are feeling  lazy, you could instead use the convenient `np.vectorize` function, which makes a function evaluate for `ndarrays` even when it is defined only for scalar arguments. However, note that this approach is essentially a shorthand for a loop, i.e., it performs the exact same computations as if you had explicitly written a loop.

```
f = np.vectorize(f)
f(xgrid)
```

> `array([ -1.,  -4.,  -9., -16., -25.])`

Answer (score 2):

When this line `f = sp.lambdify(x, sp.nsolve(x**2+y,y,2),"numpy")` is executing, first python executes `sp.nsolve(x**2+y, y, 2)`. It is the issue on your code, SymPy has one equation to resolve with 2 unknowns.

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean that I am forced to do a loop over each value in the grid, or can I still use lambdify somehow?

Comment: I would say a loop sadly

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to see whether someone can propose a more efficient solution. If no one has responded a week from now, I will mark my question as solved by you. Thanks again.